# OpenCV, Python: Perspective warping problem in aerial image stitching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

Currently, I'm working on image stitching of aerial footage. I'm using the dataset, get from [OrchardDataset](http://rsn.cs.umn.edu/index.php/Image_Mosaic_Generation#Data_Sets). First of all, thanks to some great answers on stackoverflow, especially the answer from @alkasm ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165177/13782275) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44459869/13782275)). But I having an issue, as you can see below at `Gap within the stitched image` section.

I used the `H21`, `H31`, `H41`, etc to wrap the images. The stitched image using `H21` is excellent, but when wrap the `img3` to `current stitched image` using `H31`, result shown  terrible alignment between `img3` and `current stitched image`. As the more images I wrap, the gap gets bigger and the images totally not well aligned.

Does the brillant stackoverflow community have an ideas on how can I solve this problem?

**These are the steps I use to stitch the images:**

1. Extract the frame every second from the footage and undistort the image to get rid of fish-eye effect using the provided camera calibration matrix.
2. Compute the ***SIFT*** feature descriptors. Set up macther using ***FLANN kd-tree*** and find matches between the images. Find the ***Homography*** (`H21`, `H32`, `H43` and etc, where `H21` refer to the homography which warps `imag2` into coordinates of `img1`)
3. Compose the homography with the previous homographies to get net homography using the method suggested in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165177/13782275). (Compute `H31`, `H41`, `H51`, etc)
4. Wrap the images using the answer provided in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44459869/13782275).

**Gap within the stitched image**:

I'm using the first 10 images get from [OrchardDataSet](http://rsn.cs.umn.edu/index.php/Image_Mosaic_Generation#Data_Sets).

[Stitched Image with Gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKBN5.jpg)

**Here's portion of my script:**

`main.py`

`ref_img` is the first frame (`img1`). `AdjHomoSet` contain the images to be wraped (`img2`, `img3`, `img4`, etc). `AccHomoSet` contain the net homography (`H31`, `H41`, `H51`, etc)

```
temp_mosaic = ref_img
h, w = temp_mosaic.shape[:2]
# Wrap the Images 
for x in range(1, (len(AccHomoSet)+1)):
    query_img = AdjHomoSet['H%d%d'%(x+1,(x))][1]
    M_homo = AccHomoSet['H%d1'%(x+1)]

    M_homo_inv = np.linalg.inv(M_homo)

    (shifted_transf, dst_padded) = warpPerspectivePadded(query_img, 
                                                     temp_mosaic,  
                                                     M_homo_inv)
    dst_pad_h, dst_pad_w = dst_padded.shape[:2]

    next_img_warp = cv2.warpPerspective(query_img, shifted_transf, 
                                        (dst_pad_w, dst_pad_h),
                                        flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

    # Put the base image on an enlarged palette
    enlarged_base_img = np.zeros((dst_pad_h, dst_pad_w, 3), 
                                 np.uint8)

    # Create masked composite
    (ret,data_map) = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(next_img_warp, 
                                                cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 
                                   0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # add base image
    enlarged_base_img = cv2.add(enlarged_base_img, dst_padded, 
                                mask=np.bitwise_not(data_map), 
                                dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

    final_img = cv2.add(enlarged_base_img, next_img_warp, 
                        dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

    temp_mosaic = final_img
```

`warpPerspectivePadded.py`

```
def warpPerspectivePadded(image, temp_mosaic, homography):
    src_h, src_w = image.shape[:2]
    lin_homg_pts = np.array([[0, src_w, src_w, 0], 
                             [0, 0, src_h, src_h], 
                             [1, 1, 1, 1]])

    trans_lin_homg_pts = homography.dot(lin_homg_pts)
    trans_lin_homg_pts /= trans_lin_homg_pts[2,:]

    minX = np.floor(np.min(trans_lin_homg_pts[0])).astype(int)
    minY = np.floor(np.min(trans_lin_homg_pts[1])).astype(int)
    maxX = np.ceil(np.max(trans_lin_homg_pts[0])).astype(int)
    maxY = np.ceil(np.max(trans_lin_homg_pts[1])).astype(int)

    # add translation to the transformation matrix to shift to positive values
    anchorX, anchorY = 0, 0
    transl_transf = np.eye(3,3)
    if minX < 0: 
        anchorX = -minX
        transl_transf[0,2] += anchorX
    if minY < 0:
        anchorY = -minY
        transl_transf[1,2] += anchorY
    shifted_transf = transl_transf.dot(homography)
    shifted_transf /= shifted_transf[2,2]

    # create padded destination image
    temp_mosaic_h, temp_mosaic_w = temp_mosaic.shape[:2]

    pad_widths = [anchorY, max(maxY, temp_mosaic_h) - temp_mosaic_h,
                  anchorX, max(maxX, temp_mosaic_w) - temp_mosaic_w]

    dst_padded = cv2.copyMakeBorder(temp_mosaic, pad_widths[0], 
                                    pad_widths[1],pad_widths[2], 
                                    pad_widths[3],
                                    cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    return (shifted_transf, dst_padded)
```

**Updates:**

Well, here's my code for image stitching. However, this solution is not perfect but hope it would be helpful to someone else. This solution is good enough for generating a panaroma view, `SIFT+FLANN` did the best to the dataset, [Stitched image of the dataset with Straightline flight pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83noV.jpg). The interframes alignment is terribly shifted and visible skewness is obtained when stitching the dataset with lawnmower flight pattern, [Stitched image of the dataset with lawnmower flight pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6agnb.jpg) and this solution absolutely not an ideal solution for orthomosaic.

`imageStitcher.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import time
#import math
from colorama import Style, Back
import xlsxwriter as xls
"""
Important Parameter
-------------------
detector_type (string): type of determine, "sift" or "orb"
                        Defaults to "sift".
matcher_type (string): type of determine, "flann" or "bf"
                       Defaults to "flann".
resize_ratio (int) = number needed to decrease the input images size
output_height_times (int): determines the output height based on input image height. 
                           Defaults to 2.
output_width_times (int): determines the output width based on input image width. 
                           Defaults to 4.
            
"""
detector_type = "sift"
matcher_type = "flann"
resize_ratio = 3
output_height_times = 20
output_width_times = 15
gms = False
visualize = True

image_dir = "image/Input"
key_frame = "image/Input/frame1.jpg"
output_dir = "image/Input"
    
class ImageStitching:
    def __init__(self, first_image, 
                 output_height_times = output_height_times, 
                 output_width_times = output_width_times, 
                 detector_type = detector_type, 
                 matcher_type = matcher_type):
        """This class processes every frame and generates the panorama

        Args:
            first_image (image for the first frame): first image to initialize the output size
            output_height_times (int, optional): determines the output height based on input image height. Defaults to 2.
            output_width_times (int, optional): determines the output width based on input image width. Defaults to 4.
            detector_type (str, optional): the detector for feature detection. It can be "sift" or "orb". Defaults to "sift".
        """
        self.detector_type = detector_type
        self.matcher_type = matcher_type
        if detector_type == "sift":
            # SIFT feature detector
            self.detector = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(nOctaveLayers = 3,
                                                        contrastThreshold = 0.04,
                                                        edgeThreshold = 10,
                                                        sigma = 1.6)
            if matcher_type == "flann":
                # FLANN: the randomized kd trees algorithm
                FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
                flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
                search_params = dict (checks=200)
                self.matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params,search_params)
                
            else:
                # Brute-Force matcher
                self.matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
        elif detector_type == "orb":
            # ORB feature detector
            self.detector = cv2.ORB_create()
            self.detector.setFastThreshold(0)
            if matcher_type == "flann":
                FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
                flann_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                                   table_number = 6, # 12
                                   key_size = 12,     # 20
                                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2
                search_params = dict (checks=200)
                self.matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params,search_params)
            else:
                # Brute-Force-Hamming matcher
                self.matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

        self.record = []
        self.visualize = visualize
        self.output_img = np.zeros(shape=(int(output_height_times * first_image.shape[0]), 
                                          int(output_width_times*first_image.shape[1]), 
                                          first_image.shape[2]))

        self.process_first_frame(first_image)

        # output image offset
        self.w_offset = int(self.output_img.shape[0]/2 - first_image.shape[0]/2)
        self.h_offset = int(self.output_img.shape[1]/2 - first_image.shape[1]/2)

        self.output_img[self.w_offset:self.w_offset+first_image.shape[0],
                        self.h_offset:self.h_offset+first_image.shape[1], :] = first_image
        a = self.output_img
        heightM, widthM = a.shape[:2]
        a = cv2.resize(a, (int(widthM / 4), 
                           int(heightM / 4)), 
                       interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        # cv2.imshow('output', a)
        self.H_old = np.eye(3)
        self.H_old[0, 2] = self.h_offset
        self.H_old[1, 2] = self.w_offset

    def process_first_frame(self, first_image):
        """processes the first frame for feature detection and description

        Args:
            first_image (cv2 image/np array): first image for feature detection
        """
        self.base_frame_rgb = first_image
        base_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        base_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(base_frame_gray, (5,5), 0)
        self.base_features, self.base_desc = self.detector.detectAndCompute(base_frame, None)
    
    def process_adj_frame(self, next_frame_rgb):
        """gets an image and processes that image for mosaicing

        Args:
            next_frame_rgb (np array): input of current frame for the mosaicing
        """
        self.next_frame_rgb = next_frame_rgb
        next_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(next_frame_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        next_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(next_frame_gray, (5,5), 0)
        self.next_features, self.next_desc = self.detector.detectAndCompute(next_frame, None)
        
        
        self.matchingNhomography(self.next_desc, self.base_desc)
        
        if len(self.matches) < 4:
            return
        
        print ("\n")
        self.warp(self.next_frame_rgb, self.H)
        
        # For record purpose: save into csv file later
        self.record.append([len(self.base_features), len(self.next_features), 
                            self.no_match_lr, self.no_GMSmatches, self.inlier, self.inlierRatio, self.reproError])
        
        # loop preparation
        self.H_old = self.H
        self.base_features = self.next_features
        self.base_desc = self.next_desc
        self.base_frame_rgb = self.next_frame_rgb

    def matchingNhomography(self, next_desc, base_desc):
        """matches the descriptors

        Args:
            next_desc (np array): current frame descriptor
            base_desc (np array): previous frame descriptor

        Returns:
            array: and array of matches between descriptors
        """
        # matching
        if self.detector_type == "sift":
            pair_matches = self.matcher.knnMatch(next_desc, trainDescriptors = base_desc, 
                                                 k = 2)

            """
                Store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test'
                The Lowe's ratio is refer to the journal "Distinctive 
                Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints" by 
                David G. Lowe.
            """
            lowe_ratio = 0.8
            matches = []
            for m, n in pair_matches:
                if m.distance < n.distance * lowe_ratio:
                    matches.append(m)
            self.no_match_lr = len(matches)
            # Rate of matches (Lowe's ratio test)
            rate = float(len(matches) / ((len(self.base_features) + len(self.next_features))/2))
            print (f"Rate of matches (Lowe's ratio test): {Back.RED}%f{Style.RESET_ALL}" % rate)
            

        elif self.detector_type == "orb":
            if self.matcher_type == "flann":
                matches = self.matcher.match(next_desc, base_desc)
                '''
                lowe_ratio = 0.8
                matches = []
                for m, n in pair_matches:
                    if m.distance < n.distance * lowe_ratio:
                        matches.append(m)
                '''
                self.no_match_lr = len(matches)
                # Rate of matches (Lowe's ratio test)
                rate = float(len(matches) / (len(base_desc) + len(next_desc)))
                print (f"Rate of matches (Lowe's ratio test): {Back.RED}%f{Style.RESET_ALL}" % rate)
            else:
                pair_matches = self.matcher.match(next_desc, base_desc)
                # Rate of matches (before Lowe's ratio test)
                self.no_match_lr = len(pair_matches)
                rate = float(len(pair_matches) / (len(base_desc) + len(next_desc)))
                print (f"Rate of matches: {Back.RED}%f{Style.RESET_ALL}" % rate)

        
        # Sort them in the order of their distance.
        matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
        
        # OPTIONAL: used to remove the unmatch pair match
        matches = cv2.xfeatures2d.matchGMS(self.next_frame_rgb.shape[:2], 
                                            self.base_frame_rgb.shape[:2], 
                                            self.next_features, 
                                            self.base_features, matches, 
                                            withScale = False, withRotation = False, 
                                            thresholdFactor = 6.0) if gms else matches
        self.no_GMSmatches = len(matches) if gms else 0
        # Rate of matches (GMS)
        rate = float(self.no_GMSmatches / (len(base_desc) + len(next_desc)))
        print (f"Rate of matches (GMS): {Back.CYAN}%f{Style.RESET_ALL}" % rate)

        # OPTIONAL: Obtain the maximum of 20 best matches
        # matches = matches[:min(len(matches), 20)]
        
        # Visualize the matches.
        if self.visualize:
            match_img = cv2.drawMatches(self.next_frame_rgb, self.next_features, self.base_frame_rgb, 
                                        self.base_features, matches, None,
                                        flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
            cv2.imshow('matches', match_img)
        
        self.H, self.status, self.reproError = self.findHomography(self.next_features, self.base_features, matches)
        print ('inlier/matched = %d / %d' % (np.sum(self.status), len(self.status)))
        self.inlier = np.sum(self.status)
        self.inlierRatio = float(np.sum(self.status)) / float(len(self.status))
        print ('inlierRatio = ', self.inlierRatio)
        # len(status) - np.sum(status) = number of detected outliers
        
        ''' 
            TODO - 
                To minimize or get rid of cumulative homography error is use block bundle adjustnment
                Suggested from "Multi View Image Stitching of Planar Surfaces on Mobile Devices"
                Using 3-dimentional multiplication to find cumulative homography is very sensitive
                to homography error.
        '''
        # 3-dimensional multiplication to find cumulative homography to the reference keyframe
        self.H = np.matmul(self.H_old, self.H) 
        self.H = self.H/self.H[2,2]
        self.matches = matches
        return matches
    
    @ staticmethod
    def findHomography(base_features, next_features, matches):
        """gets two matches and calculate the homography between two images

        Args:
            base_features (np array): keypoints of image 1
            next_features (np_array): keypoints of image 2
            matches (np array): matches between keypoints in image 1 and image 2

        Returns:
            np arrat of shape [3,3]: Homography matrix
        """
        
        kp1 = []
        kp2 = []
        for match in matches:
            kp1.append(base_features[match.queryIdx])
            kp2.append(next_features[match.trainIdx])
        p1_array = np.array([k.pt for k in kp1])
        p2_array = np.array([k.pt for k in kp2])
        
        homography, status = cv2.findHomography(p1_array, p2_array, method = cv2.RANSAC, 
                                                    ransacReprojThreshold = 5.0,
                                                    mask = None,
                                                    maxIters = 2000,
                                                    confidence = 0.995)
        
        #### Finding the euclidean distance error ####
        list1 = np.array(p2_array)    
        list2 = np.array(p1_array)
        list2 = np.reshape(list2, (len(list2), 2))
        ones = np.ones(len(list1))
        TestPoints = np.transpose(np.reshape(list1, (len(list1), 2)))
        print ("Length:", np.shape(TestPoints), np.shape(ones))
        TestPointsHom = np.vstack((TestPoints, ones))
        print ("Homogenous Points:", np.shape(TestPointsHom))
    
        projectedPointsH = np.matmul(homography, TestPointsHom)  # projecting the points in test image to collage image using homography matrix    
        projectedPointsNH = np.transpose(np.array([np.true_divide(projectedPointsH[0,:], projectedPointsH[2,:]), np.true_divide(projectedPointsH[1,:], projectedPointsH[2,:])]))
        
        print ("list2 shape:", np.shape(list2))
        print ("NH Points shape:", np.shape(projectedPointsNH))
        print ("Raw Error Vector:", np.shape(np.linalg.norm(projectedPointsNH-list2, axis=1)))
        Error = int(np.sum(np.linalg.norm(projectedPointsNH-list2, axis=1)))
        print ("Total Error:", Error)
        AvgError = np.divide(np.array(Error), np.array(len(list1)))
        print ("Average Error:", AvgError)
        
        ################## 
        return homography, status, AvgError

    def warp(self, next_frame_rgb, H):
        """ warps the current frame based of calculated homography H

        Args:
            next_frame_rgb (np array): current frame
            H (np array of shape [3,3]): homography matrix

        Returns:
            np array: image output of mosaicing
        """
        warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(
            next_frame_rgb, H, (self.output_img.shape[1], self.output_img.shape[0]), 
            flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            
        transformed_corners = self.get_transformed_corners(next_frame_rgb, H)
        warped_img = self.draw_border(warped_img, transformed_corners)
        
        self.output_img[warped_img > 0] = warped_img[warped_img > 0]
        output_temp = np.copy(self.output_img)
        output_temp = self.draw_border(output_temp, transformed_corners, color=(0, 0, 255))
        
        # Visualize the stitched result
        if self.visualize:
            output_temp_copy = output_temp/255.
            output_temp_copy = cv2.normalize(output_temp_copy, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)  # convert float64 to unit8
            size = 720
            heightM, widthM = output_temp_copy.shape[:2]
            ratio = size / float(heightM)
            output_temp_copy = cv2.resize(output_temp_copy, (int(ratio * widthM), size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            cv2.imshow('output',  output_temp_copy)

        return self.output_img

    @ staticmethod
    def get_transformed_corners(next_frame_rgb, H):
        """finds the corner of the current frame after warp

        Args:
            next_frame_rgb (np array): current frame
            H (np array of shape [3,3]): Homography matrix 

        Returns:
            [np array]: a list of 4 corner points after warping
        """
        corner_0 = np.array([0, 0])
        corner_1 = np.array([next_frame_rgb.shape[1], 0])
        corner_2 = np.array([next_frame_rgb.shape[1], next_frame_rgb.shape[0]])
        corner_3 = np.array([0, next_frame_rgb.shape[0]])

        corners = np.array([[corner_0, corner_1, corner_2, corner_3]], dtype=np.float32)
        transformed_corners = cv2.perspectiveTransform(corners, H)

        transformed_corners = np.array(transformed_corners, dtype=np.int32)
        # output_temp = np.copy(output_img)
        # mask = np.zeros(shape=(output_temp.shape[0], output_temp.shape[1], 1))
        # cv2.fillPoly(mask, transformed_corners, color=(1, 0, 0))
        # cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

        return transformed_corners

    def draw_border(self, image, corners, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        """This functions draw rectancle border

        Args:
            image ([type]): current mosaiced output
            corners (np array): list of corner points
            color (tuple, optional): color of the border lines. Defaults to (0, 0, 0).

        Returns:
            np array: the output image with border
        """
        for i in range(corners.shape[1]-1, -1, -1):
            cv2.line(image, tuple(corners[0, i, :]), tuple(
                corners[0, i-1, :]), thickness=5, color=color)
        return image
    
    @staticmethod
    def stitchedimg_crop(stitched_img):
        """This functions crop the black edge

        Args:
            stitched_img (np array): stitched image with black edge

        Returns:
            np array: the output image with no black edge
        """
        stitched_img = cv2.normalize(stitched_img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)  # convert float64 to unit8
        # Crop black edges
        stitched_img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(stitched_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(stitched_img_gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        dino, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        print ("Cropping black edge of stitched image ...")
        print ("Found %d contours...\n" % (len(contours)))
        
        max_area = 0
        best_rect = (0,0,0,0)
    
        for cnt in contours:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    
            deltaHeight = h-y
            deltaWidth = w-x
            if deltaHeight < 0 or deltaWidth < 0:
                deltaHeight = h+y
                deltaWidth = w+x
            
            area = deltaHeight * deltaWidth
    
            if ( area > max_area and deltaHeight > 0 and deltaWidth > 0):
                max_area = area
                best_rect = (x,y,w,h)
        
        if ( max_area > 0 ):
            final_img_crop = stitched_img[best_rect[1]:best_rect[1]+best_rect[3],
                    best_rect[0]:best_rect[0]+best_rect[2]]
        
        return final_img_crop

def main():
    images = sorted(glob.glob(image_dir + "/*.jpg"), 
                    key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0][5:]))
    # read the first frame
    first_frame = cv2.imread(key_frame)
    heightM, widthM = first_frame.shape[:2]
    first_frame = cv2.resize(first_frame, (int(widthM / resize_ratio), 
                                            int(heightM / resize_ratio)), 
                              interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    image_stitching = ImageStitching(first_frame)
    round = 2
    for next_img_path in images[1:]:
        print (f'Reading {Back.YELLOW}%s{Style.RESET_ALL}...' % next_img_path)
        next_frame_rgb = cv2.imread(next_img_path)
        heightM, widthM = next_frame_rgb.shape[:2]
        next_frame_rgb = cv2.resize(next_frame_rgb, (int(widthM / resize_ratio), 
                                           int(heightM / resize_ratio)), 
                               interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        print ("Stitching %d / %d of image ..." % (round,len(images)))
        # process each frame
        image_stitching.process_adj_frame(next_frame_rgb)
        
        round += 1
        if round > len(images):
            print ("Please press 'q' to continue the process ...")
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    # cv2.imwrite('mosaic.jpg', image_stitching.output_img)
    final_img_crop = image_stitching.stitchedimg_crop(image_stitching.output_img)

    print ("Image stitching done ...")
    cv2.imwrite("%s/Normal.JPG" % output_dir, final_img_crop)
    
    # Save important results into csv file
    tuplelist = tuple(image_stitching.record)
    workbook = xls.Workbook('Normal.xlsx') 
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Normal") 
    row = 0
    col = 0
    worksheet.write(row, col, 'number_pairs')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, 'basefeature')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, 'nextfeature') 
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, 'no_match_lr')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 4, 'match_rate')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 5, 'no_GMSmatches (OFF)')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 6, 'gms_match_rate')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 7, 'inlier')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 8, 'inlierratio')
    worksheet.write(row, col + 9, 'reproerror')
    row += 1
    number = 1
    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row. 
    for basefeature, nextfeature, no_match_lr, no_GMSmatches, inlier, inlierratio, reproerror in (tuplelist): 
        worksheet.write(row, col, number) 
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, basefeature)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 2, nextfeature) 
        worksheet.write(row, col + 3, no_match_lr)
        match_rate = no_match_lr / ((basefeature+nextfeature)/2)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 4, match_rate)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 5, no_GMSmatches)
        gms_match_rate = no_GMSmatches / ((basefeature+nextfeature)/2)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 6, gms_match_rate)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 7, inlier)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 8, inlierratio)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 9, reproerror)
        number += 1
        row += 1
      
    workbook.close()

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""" Main """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    program_start = time.process_time()
    main()
    program_end = time.process_time()
    print (f'Program elapsed time: {Back.GREEN}%s s{Style.RESET_ALL}\n' % str(program_end-program_start))
```

Comment: in increnental image stitching there isn inevitable drift. To reduce (or distribute) the error in a global solution, bundle adjustment can be used.

Comment: @Micka do you have any recommended blog or github link regrading the bundle adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I changed the way of warping the image using the approach provided by Jahaniam [Real Time Video Mosaic](https://github.com/jahaniam/Real-time-Video-Mosaic). He locates the reference image at the middle of preset size of blank image and compute the subsequent homography and warp the adjacent images to the reference image.

[Example of stitched image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CamlL.jpg)

Comment: If possible, could you please share your solution, how did you achieve image stitching? That will help in understanding. Thanks

Comment: @ganesh 
1. Resizing image and convert the image to grayscale
2. Applying Gaussian Blur
3. Performing feature extraction and feature description using SIFT
4. Feature matching using FLANN (randomized kd tree)
5. Storing good matches using Lowe's ratio test
6. Compute homography matrix using RANSAC (remove outliers)
7. Calculate inlier ratio
8. Warping the adjacent image onto the key frame

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually I have tried those steps with different methods also but not able to get perfect result. pls check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543804/image-stitching-problem-using-python-and-opencv  If possible could you please provide your solution code for all steps that you mentioned, that will helpful to try out? Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: I have attached my solution code in the post. I'm not an expert in this field, but I hope the code would be helpful to you. In order to get a perfect result (good interframes alignment, no skewness), you need to implement some methods that can compare the images globally, for example, bundle adjustment. FYI, the cumulative homography error will get bigger when more interframe homography estimation iscomputed. And the homography estimation is very sensitive to the cumulative homography error during the homography matrix computation. Bundle adjustment might be the only way to mitigate the errors

Comment: And this is the error that cause my results obtain visible skewness and interframe misalignment.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out the time to give updates and providing help, guidance. I will try out your solution and will check, learn more about this. Thanks for giving me knowledge on this. Really appreciate your work. Thanks